# Android widget settings edit option disabled

Tags: android-intent, android-widget, android-manifest, android-preferences

I have widget with configuration page.
On adding widget to main screen I can set some configuration.

After adding widget, while dragging, I see two buttons in upper side of the screen:
[EDIT] | [DELETE]
where I can only delete widget from homescreen. Edit button is disabled.

How can I enable this "EDIT" ability so I can drag widget on that "[EDIT]" place to open configuration page after adding widget to screen?

Answer (score -1):

### DaysLeftWidget

```
public WidgetConfiguration(Context context, int widgetId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.widgetId = widgetId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return getPrefs().getString(getFullKeyName("title"), null);
    }

public SimpleDate getSimpleDate() {
    int year, month, day;
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPrefs();
    year = prefs.getInt(getFullKeyName("date_year"), 0);
    month = prefs.getInt(getFullKeyName("date_month"), 0);
    day = prefs.getInt(getFullKeyName("date_day"), 0);
    if (year == 0 || month == 0 || day == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return new SimpleDate(year, month, day);
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPrefsEditor();
    editor.putString(getFullKeyName("title"), title);
    editor.commit();
}

public void setSimpleDate(SimpleDate date) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPrefsEditor();
    int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

    if (date != null) {
        year = date.getYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        day = date.getDay();
    }

    editor.putInt(getFullKeyName("date_year"), year);
    editor.putInt(getFullKeyName("date_month"), month);
    editor.putInt(getFullKeyName("date_day"), day);

    editor.commit();
}

public void clear() {
    setTitle(null);
    setSimpleDate(null);
}

protected SharedPreferences getPrefs() {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

protected String getFullKeyName(String keyName) {
    return PREF_PREFIX + widgetId + "_" + keyName;
}

protected SharedPreferences.Editor getPrefsEditor() {
    return getPrefs().edit();
}
```

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Free.daysleft